# Silverlight MVVM header detail

Tags: mvvm, silverlight, header, detailsview

So lets say i have an OrderModel and an OrderViewModel. I have the Supplier, Order Date, etc properties on both the ViewModel and the Model and they are linked up. Seen examples on this and seems straighforward enough, although somewhat duplicated in terms of writing setters/getters.

Now what do I do with the OrderDetails? In my model I would have a List.

Do I have an OrderDetailViewModel for the OrderDetail? If so then how does the OrderViewModel provide that? As an ObservableCollection? And if so how do you keep that in sync with the original List?

This is where I haven't seen a decent example. If there is one out there someone could point me to, I'd appreciate it. I liek the concept of the MVVM but I am starting to thing its a hell of a lot of overhead. Why not just have the ViewModel handle the model part as well. In day to day LOB apps is there really that much difference between the two to warrant all the code that true MVVM seems to required?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is what you need: http://jonas.follesoe.no/SpeakingAtMSDNLiveNextMonth.aspx

A translation on google gives this as the abstract for the talk:

> Silverlight 2 was released this autumn, and lays a good foundation for developers who want to create rich Internet applications (RIA) based on. NET. In this session we in Depth in Silverlight 2 that development and the benefits of choosing Silverlight 2 as a platform for data-centric business applications. The session will cover among other things, data access via secured WCF services, how to structure the code using the Model-View-View Model pattern (MVVM), how to write code, designers can work with, and easy-Blend tips for developers. The session will be built around a dive log application where the code will be available after the presentation.

However in the mean time Jonas has already talked about MVVM here:

http://jonas.follesoe.no/YouCardRevisitedImplementingTheViewModelPattern.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to keep your ObservableCollections synchronised between the model and view model:

```
/// <summary>
/// Keeps one collection synchronised with another.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="Source">The type of the source items.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="Destination">The type of the destination items.</typeparam>
public class CollectionSync<Source, Destination>
{
    private readonly Func<Source, Destination> _destItemFactory;
    private readonly Action<Destination>       _destItemRemover;

    private readonly IList<Destination> _destList;
    private readonly IList<Source>      _sourceList;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CollectionSync&lt;Source, Destination&gt;"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceList">The source list.</param>
    /// <param name="destList">The destination list.</param>
    /// <param name="destItemFactory">Factory method which creates a Destination for a given Source.</param>
    /// <param name="destItemRemover">Method called when a Destination is removed.</param>
    public CollectionSync(IList<Source> sourceList,
                          IList<Destination> destList,
                          Func<Source, Destination> destItemFactory,
                          Action<Destination> destItemRemover)
    {
        _destItemFactory = destItemFactory;
        _destItemRemover = destItemRemover;
        _sourceList = sourceList;
        _destList = destList;

        ((INotifyCollectionChanged) _sourceList).CollectionChanged += SourceCollection_CollectionChanged;

        PopulateWithAllItems();
    }

    private void PopulateWithAllItems()
    {
        foreach (Source sourceItem in _sourceList)
            _destList.Add(_destItemFactory(sourceItem));
    }

    private void SourceCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                OnItemsAdded(args.NewStartingIndex, args.NewItems);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                OnItemsRemoved(args.OldStartingIndex, args.OldItems);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                OnItemsReset();
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    private void OnItemsReset()
    {
        _destList.Clear();
        PopulateWithAllItems();
    }

    private void OnItemsRemoved(int index, ICollection items)
    {
        int itemCount = items.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
        {
            Destination removed = _destList[index];
            _destList.RemoveAt(index);
            if (_destItemRemover != null)
                _destItemRemover(removed);
        }
    }

    private void OnItemsAdded(int index, IList items)
    {
        int itemIndex = index;
        foreach (Source item in items)
        {
            // Add to Items collection
            _destList.Insert(itemIndex, _destItemFactory(item));
            itemIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Taking your Order/OrderDetails example, in your Order view model you would hook up the two ObservableCollections like this:

```
_modelToViewModelSync = new CollectionSync<IOrderDetail, OrderDetailViewModel>(
    orderDetailModels,                 // the list of your order details models
    OrderDetails,                      // the list of order details view models exposed by the Order view model
    x => new OrderDetailViewModel(x),  // factory method to create a view model
    null);                             // do something here if you care when your view models are removed
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the question "Do I need another view model", my answer is this:  If all your view is doing is showing the model data, there is no harm in binding directly to the order directly.  Creating a ViewModel for this would be very much redundant.  The time when the ViewModel needs to be created is when you have logic or state in the "order detail" screen that needs to be represented.  Instead of adding that to the model, you create a ViewModel at that time.

As far as keeping those items in sync, Similar to GraemeF, I have created a Binder class that is uses reflection to bind two values together.  It keeps my model and viewmodel properties in sync, and it can be used to keep other things in sync, like this particular collection.  There is some overhead in creating a binder like this, but once it is done, you can specify data correlations in a functional way, which is really nice.